# Proguard suddenly errors

Tags: android, proguard

I am using Proguard in my app.
One day, it suddenly started to give me these errors. It's like Proguard can't find any of my classes.
What could I have done to trigger this and how can I fix this?
This is my proguard settings:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-libraryjars adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars libs/FlurryAgent.jar
-libraryjars libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar
-libraryjars libs/crittercism_v3_0_7_sdkonly.jar
-libraryjars libs/gson-2.2.2.jar
-libraryjars libs/urbanairship-lib-2.1.4.jar


# Gson

# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
# Gson deserialization uses introspection to get the json entry names for the field names,
# so we do not want to change them.
-keep class com.ftbpro.data.model.** { *; }


# Admob & Analytics
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
-keep public class com.google.** {*;}

# Flurry
-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flurry.**

# Crittercism
-keep public class com.crittercism.**
-keepclassmembers public class com.crittercism.*
{
    *;
}

#FB method signature workaround
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keep class android.webkit.WebViewClient
-keep class * extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {
    <methods>;
}
```

This are my libs:

```
    -libraryjars libs/android-query.0.25.10.jar
-libraryjars libs/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars libs/FlurryAgent.jar
-libraryjars libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar
-libraryjars libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar
-libraryjars libs/crittercism_v3_0_7_sdkonly.jar
-libraryjars libs/gson-2.2.2.jar
-libraryjars libs/urbanairship-lib-2.1.4.jar
```

This is the error massages:

```
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find superclass or interface com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.FriendPickerFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.facebook.widget.FriendPickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.FriendPickerFragment: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getString(int)' in class com.facebook.widget.FriendPickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader: can't find referenced method 'boolean isStarted()' in class com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View getView()' in class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getString(int)' in class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment$LoadingStrategy: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager getLoaderManager()' in class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment$LoadingStrategy: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View getView()' in class com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment: can't find referenced method 'void onAttach(android.app.Activity)' in class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getString(int)' in class com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment$1: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getString(int,java.lang.Object[])' in class com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.Resources getResources()' in class com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment: can't find referenced method 'void onCreate(android.os.Bundle)' in class com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment: can't find referenced method 'void setRetainInstance(boolean)' in class com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment: can't find referenced method 'void onResume()' in class com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment: can't find referenced method 'boolean isAdded()' in class com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.Application: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.callback.BitmapAjaxCallback
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.Application: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.callback.BitmapAjaxCallback
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.EventsFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.EventsFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.EventsFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.Resources getResources()' in class com.ftbpro.app.EventsFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.EventsFragment$1: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.EventsFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.EventsFragment$1: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Intent getIntent()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.EventsFragment$LiveEventsAdapter: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.EventsFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.AQuery
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.AQuery
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.Resources getResources()' in class com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced method 'void startActivity(android.content.Intent)' in class com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.AQuery
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.AQuery
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.AQuery
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.AQuery
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.AQuery
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.callback.ImageOptions
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.callback.ImageOptions
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.callback.ImageOptions
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.callback.ImageOptions
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.AQuery
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.AQuery
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.callback.ImageOptions
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment$FeedListAdapter: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment$MorePostsLoaderTask: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment$NewPostsLoaderTask: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment$PullToRefreshHeader: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.FeedListFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity: can't find referenced method 'void setContentView(int)' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.Resources getResources()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getString(int)' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Intent getIntent()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View findViewById(int)' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity: can't find referenced method 'void startActivity(android.content.Intent)' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity: can't find referenced method 'void finish()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity$1: can't find referenced method 'void startActivity(android.content.Intent)' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity$1: can't find referenced method 'void finish()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity$DownloadLiveMatchTask: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Intent getIntent()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity$DownloadLiveMatchTask: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.AssetManager getAssets()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity$DownloadLiveMatchTask: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View findViewById(int)' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity$DownloadLiveMatchTask: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.Resources getResources()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity$DownloadLiveMatchTask: can't find referenced method 'void finish()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'void setContentView(int)' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View findViewById(int)' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager()' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getString(int)' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'boolean isTaskRoot()' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.util.AQUtility
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.util.AQUtility
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'void startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int)' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'void startActivity(android.content.Intent)' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.AssetManager getAssets()' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.Resources getResources()' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager getPackageManager()' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getPackageName()' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.content.ComponentName startService(android.content.Intent)' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'android.view.WindowManager getWindowManager()' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'java.io.File getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.util.AQUtility
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.callback.BitmapAjaxCallback
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.callback.BitmapAjaxCallback
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity: can't find referenced class com.androidquery.callback.BitmapAjaxCallback
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity$LoadLiveMatchTask: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View findViewById(int)' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity$PushNotificationsRegistrationTask: can't find referenced method 'android.content.ContentResolver getContentResolver()' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning:



com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity$PushNotificationsRegistrationTask: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Context getApplicationContext()' in class com.ftbpro.app.MainActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.PaneFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.PaneFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.RankTableFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.RankTableFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.RankTableFragment$DataLoaderTask: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.RankTableFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.RankTableFragment$DataLoaderTask: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.Resources getResources()' in class com.ftbpro.app.RankTableFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.RankTableFragment$RankAdapter: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.RankTableFragment
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View getView()' in class com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced method 'void startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int)' in class com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.Resources getResources()' in class com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet$PostAndGetReactions: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet$PostAndGetReactions: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager()' in class com.ftbpro.app.LiveMatchActivity
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet$PostAndGetReactions: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View getView()' in class com.ftbpro.app.ReactionsFragmet
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: there were 39 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] Warning: there were 76 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]          You may need to recompile the code or update the library versions.
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:330)
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:212)
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:87)
[2013-06-19 10:30:15 - FTBPro]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are the libs you are using and share your proguard config

Comment: post ur proguard cfg file content!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to add these line very first on our proguard.cfg file on your project as below:

```
-ignorewarnings
```

add all references are checked on your project properties import and export like below screen shots:

[image]

Comment: I see now that it's not fully doing what it did before. the file size is two times bigger than what it was before the sudden warnings... it's not shrinking enough. I guess that it's not working on all the class it warned me about. what do you say?

Comment: @roiberg can you referenced jar files checked on the order and export on your project properties?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you question.

Comment: Hurrah!! Thank you very very much... you are saving my time